# Show locations on a map in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, openlayers

in my asp.net application i need to display on a map (google map but i also have a shapefile of the roads ) the locations of about a thousand car accidents.
This is my very first approach with this world and i'm getting confused.
I can see a long list of framework and libraries ( OpenLayers, SharpMap, GoogleMaps Api, etc... ) but i dont' know which is the best for my pourpose.

Could you please help me to find the way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to add markers to the map it's really easy, have a look at the [Marker examples on this page](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/index.html). (View the source.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the answers to these questions:

[Google Maps - Easy way in ASP.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360677/google-maps-easy-way-in-asp-net)

[Best .NET Wrapper for Google Maps or Yahoo Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070/best-net-wrapper-for-google-maps-or-yahoo-maps)

[ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/22/436166.aspx) suggests this [how-to article](http://dotnet.sys-con.com/node/171162).

And here's a [Code Project how-to](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/LatLaysFlat-Part1.aspx).